# Prolog , find neighbors of a graph

Tags: list, prolog, graph-theory, neighbours

Given a graph

```
G = [1 - 5, 2 - 4, 2 - 6, 3 - 4, 3 - 6, 3 - 9, 4 - 7, 5 - 7, 6 - 7, 6 - 8, 6 - 9]
```

I must find all neighbors for each node , and create a list with this form

```
Graph   = [(1, [5]), (2, [4, 6]), (3, [4, 6, 9]), (4, [2, 3, 7]), (5, [1, 7]), (6, [2, 3, 7, 8, 9]), (7, [4, 5, 6]), (8, [6]), (9, [3, 6])].
```

Here is my approach :

```
search_for_neighbors(Ne,V,Ne,V).
search_for_neighbors(V,V,Ne,Ne).
search_for_neighbors(_,_,_,0).

neigh(_,[],_).
neigh(N,[(V - Ne)|T],Graph) :-
   neigh(N,T,Graph1),
   search_for_neighbors(N,V,Ne,Result),
   add_first(Result,Graph1,Graph).

allneigh(0,_,_).
allneigh(N,G,L) :-
   N1 is N - 1,
   allneigh(N1,G,L1),
   neigh(N,G,L2),
   add_last((N,L2),L1,L).

add_first(0, L, L).
add_first(X, L, [X|L]). 

add_last(X, [], [X]).
add_last(X, [Y|L1], [Y|L2]):- add_last(X,L1,L2).
```

I run my Prolog code :

```
?- allneigh(9,[1 - 5, 2 - 4, 2 - 6, 3 - 4, 3 - 6, 3 - 9, 4 - 7, 5 - 7, 6 - 7, 6 - 8, 6 - 9],G).
```

And this is my result ,

```
G = [(1, [5|_464]), (2, [4, 6|_508]), (3, [4, 6, 9|_556]), (4, [2, 3, 7|_606]), (5, [1, 7|_658]), (6, [2, 3, 7, 8, 9|_712]), (7, [4, 5, 6|_769]), (8, [6|_827]), (9, [3, 6|_883])]
```

Why do I have this behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: because of the second underscore (`_`) in the first line of `neigh/3`:

```
neigh(_,[],_).
%          ^ culprint
```

Since you do recursion on that part, all lists you generate are *open ended*:

```
?- neigh(N,[1 - 5, 2 - 4, 2 - 6, 3 - 4, 3 - 6, 3 - 9, 4 - 7, 5 - 7, 6 - 7, 6 - 8, 6 - 9],L).
N = 9,
L = [3, 6|_G4581] ;
N = 9,
L = [0, 3, 6|_G4581] ;
N = 9,
L = [0, 3, 6|_G4581] ;
N = 9,
L = [0, 0, 3, 6|_G4581] ;
```

You can perform a quick fix by using an empty list, like:

```
neigh(_,[],[]).
```

But there are more issues:

- `add_first/3` backtracks even if you add `0`, since the second line of `add_first/3` does *not* exclude `X` being `0`.
- why do you generate an `0` anyway?

In general I would say the code is not much "declarative" and uses a lot of conventions (like using an `0`) to filter out corner cases and edge cases. You also use `add_last/3`, etc. which is usually something you want to avoid since it is quite inefficient.

## Solution using builtins

Let us first define a helper function `range(N,L).` that for a given `N`, generates a list `L=[1,2,...,N]`:

```
range(N,L) :-
    range(1,N,L).

range(I,N,[]) :-
    I > N.
range(I,N,[I|L]) :-
    I =< N,
    I1 is I+1,
    range(I1,N,L).
```

Now we can use a complex *one-liner* to construct such a graph:

```
allneigh(N,G,L) :-
    range(N,Vs),
    findall((X,Ys),
        setof(Y,(member(X,Vs),(member(X-Y,G);member(Y-X,G))),Ys),
    L).
```

Which gives:

```
?- allneigh(9,[1 - 5, 2 - 4, 2 - 6, 3 - 4, 3 - 6, 3 - 9, 4 - 7, 5 - 7, 6 - 7, 6 - 8, 6 - 9],G).
G = [ (1, [5]), (2, [4, 6]), (3, [4, 6, 9]), (4, [2, 3, 7]), (5, [1, 7]), (6, [2, 3|...]), (7, [4|...]), (8, [...]), (..., ...)] [write]
G = [ (1, [5]), (2, [4, 6]), (3, [4, 6, 9]), (4, [2, 3, 7]), (5, [1, 7]), (6, [2, 3, 7, 8, 9]), (7, [4, 5, 6]), (8, [6]), (9, [3, 6])] ;
```

(the second line is only the output written in full).

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use foldl :

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

all_neighbors(G, N) :-
    foldl(\X^Y^Z^(X = A - B,
                 (   select((A,V), Y, Y1)
                 ->   append(V, [B], V1),
                      sort([(A,V1) | Y1], Y2)
                 ;   sort([(A,[B])| Y], Y2)),
                 (   select((B,W), Y2, Y3)
                 ->   append(W, [A], V2),
                     sort([(B,V2)|Y3], Z)
                 ;   sort([(B,[A]) | Y2], Z))),
          G, [], N).
```

The result

```
 ?- all_neighbors( [1-5,2-4,2-6,3-4,3-6,3-9,4-7,5-7,6-7,6-8,6-9], N).
 N = [(1,[5]),(2,[4,6]),(3,[4,6,9]),(4,[2,3,7]),(5,[1,7]),(6,[2,3,7,8,9]),(7,[4,5,6]),(8,[6]),(9,[3,6])].
```